Interesting problem on writing a number as the sum of integer powers
This is an interesting problem that came to my mind. I've got a feeling somebody has already solved this before, but I couldn't find any solutions. I'm trying my best to formulate both the problem and my attempt at a solution. Anyway...
If you are in a hurry, skip to Precise problem statement.
Introduction to the problem
Let's say we have $n$ square blocks with dimensions 1×1, and we have to "pack" them in square containers that have dimensions 1×1, 2×2, 3×3, etc. We also have to fill every container we use all the way, so we cannot put 7 blocks in a 3×3 container.
For example, we can "pack" 27 squares into a 5×5 container, and two 1×1 containers:

We would represent this algebraically as $27 = 5^2 + 1^2 + 1^2$, and so this packing method uses 3 containers.
But there are multiple ways to pack 27 squares even under these constraints. Another way is via a 4×4, a 3×3, and two 1×1 containers:

We would represent this as $27 = 4^2 + 3^2 + 1^2 + 1^2$. It can be seen that more containers are needed with this packing method compared to the previous method.
Problem, extension 1
Now suppose that you can use the same containers, as well as these containers with any square-sized holes with integer side lengths cut into them, to "pack" the square blocks.
With this extension, we can pack 27 squares by starting with a 6×6 container and cutting a 3×3 hole in it:

This is $27 = 6^2 - 3^2$.
We can sum up the number of containers used and holes cut for any of the 3 packing methods so far, and call that number $s$ the operation count. Using this definition, method 1 has an operation count of 3, method 2 has an operation count of 4, and method 3 has an operation count of only 2.
Problem, extension 2
Now suppose that the blocks and containers are 3-dimensional instead, so that each block is 1×1×1, and the containers (and holes) are 1×1×1, 2×2×2, 3×3×3, etc.
In this case, 27 can be packed perfectly in a 3×3×3 container with an operation count of just 1.
It's not hard to also imagine when the blocks and containers are $p$-dimensional instead, where $p \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. There will be at least one combination of containers and holes that can pack $n$ squares; each combination is associated with some operation count $s$. Some of these combinations are optimal: that is, they have the minimum value for $s$ out of all possible combinations.
Now the problem can be mathematically formalized below.
Precise problem statement
Every number $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be written in the form
$$n = c_1 \cdot 1^p + c_2 \cdot 2^p + c_3 \cdot 3^p + \dots$$
where $c_1, c_2, c_3, \dots \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. (A trivial way to do this is to set $c_1=n$ and all other coefficients to 0)
For each way that $n$ can be written, let $s=|c_1| + |c_2| + |c_3| + \dots$
Let $m(n,p) \in \mathbb{N}$ be the minimum $s$ value achievable from the given $n$ and $p$ value.
For instance, with the block-and-container examples shown above,

$m(27,2)=2$, achieved with $c_6 = 1$, $c_3 = -1$, and 0 for all other coefficients
$m(27,3)=1$, achieved with $c_3 = 1$, and 0 for all other coefficients

Questions
Is there an explicit formula for $m(n,p)$?

If so, what is it?

And what kind of expression is it? Is it an:

arithmetic expression?
polynomial expression?
algebraic expression?
closed-form expression?
analytic expression?




If not, why not?

My attempt
I managed to deduce a few properties of the $m(n,p)$ function, but I got stuck after that.
Properties of $m(n,p)$

$m(0,p) = 0$ for all $p$ in $m$'s domain

This is achieved by setting every coefficient to 0, getting a minimum $s$ of $|0| + |0| + \dots = 0$. In fact, the only way that $m(n,p)$ can be 0 is if $n=0$.


If $n=\pm I^p$ for some $I \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then $m(n,p)=1$. Otherwise, $m(n,p) \ge 2$.

The restriction on $I$ and $p$ imply that $I^p \ne 0$, so $m(\pm I^p,p) \ne 0$.
With that, setting $c_I = \pm 1$ achieves the desired result $n = \pm 1 \cdot I^p$, with $s=|\pm 1| = 1$. In fact, if the absolute sum of the coefficients is 1, then the only obtainable values of $n$ are $\pm I^p$ for some positive integer $I$.
If $n \ne \pm I^p$ for all $I \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then from property (1) and (2.2), $m(n,p) \ne 0$ and $m(n,p) \ne 1$. Therefore, $m(n,p) \ge 2$ in this case.


If $n = A^p + B^p$ or $n = A^p - B^p$ or $n = -A^p - B^p$ for $A,B \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, AND $n \ne \pm I^p$ for all $I \in \mathbb{N}$, then $m(n,p) = 2$.

Yes, $I \in \mathbb{N}$ is not a typo, since if $n=0$ then $I=0$, and property (1) would apply instead of this one.
In this property, $c_A$ and $c_B$ would be set to $\pm 1$, matching the signs of $A$ and $B$. All other coefficients would be set to 0. According to property (2), this must be the minimum $s$ that $m(n,p)$ is supposed to output.



Corollary
If $p=1$, then property (1) implies $m(0,1)=0$, and property (2) implies $m(n,1)=1$ for $n \ne 0$. (This is because one can always express $n$ as $\pm I^1$ by choosing $I=n$.)
Therefore:
$$m(n,1) = |\mathrm{sgn}(n)|$$
where $\mathrm{sgn}(n)$ is the signum (a.k.a. sign) function taking $n$ as the input.
Lemmas
Substituting $B=A$ for property (3) yields:

$m(\pm 2I^p, p)=2$ for all $I \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, if $p \ne 1$

For $p \ne 1$, $2I^p$ is guaranteed not to be a "perfect power", i.e. not representable as $V^p$ for all $V \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, as 2 isn't a "perfect power".



Substituting $B=1$ for property (3) yields:

$m(\pm I^p \pm 1, p)=2$ for all $I \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, if $p \ne 1$

For $p \ne 1$, $I^p \pm 1$ is guaranteed not to be a "perfect power", since the restriction on $p$ means that "perfect powers" are at least $2^2 - 1^2 = 3 > 1$ away from each other.




Edit 1: Further thoughts
Since
$$n = c_1 \cdot 1^p + c_2 \cdot 2^p + c_3 \cdot 3^p + \dots$$
and
$$s=|c_1| + |c_2| + |c_3| + \dots$$
are what we care about for the most part, I noticed that I can define two vectors,
$$\mathbf{k} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\mathbf{r} = \begin{bmatrix} 1^p \\ 2^p \\ 3^p \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix}$$
With these vectors defined, I can now say that
$$n = \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}$$
Where $\mathbf{k}$ encodes one way of choosing the coefficients $c_i$, where $i$ is a positive integer; $\mathbf{r}$ encodes the squares/cubes/higher powers that are being worked with.
Furthermore, based on the definitions of $s$ and $\mathbf{k}$, $s$ can also be interpreted as the taxicab distance from the origin $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix}$ to the vector $\mathbf{k}$.
Now the problem becomes:
Problem rephrased in terms of vectors
Given two vectors
$$\mathbf{k} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix}, \ c_1, c_2, c_3, \dots \in \mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$\mathbf{r} = \begin{bmatrix} 1^p \\ 2^p \\ 3^p \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix}, \ p \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$
Let
$$n = \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
for some fixed $n$ and $\mathbf{r}$, and let
$$s = |c_1| + |c_2| + |c_3| + \dots$$
be the taxicab distance from the 0 vector to $\mathbf{k}$.
There may be multiple $\mathbf{k}$ vectors that satisfy the dot product, but only some will have the minimum value of $s$.
Let this minimum be defined as a function, $m(n,p) \in \mathbb{N}$.
Does a formula exist for $m(n,p)$? If so, what kind of expression is it? If not, why not?
Honestly, I'm not sure if this makes the question any more approachable, since $\mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are infinite-dimensional vectors. Taking the taxicab distance of two infite-dimensional vectors also seems like a bizarre idea.

Any suggestions on how I should carry on would be deeply appreciated.

It looks like you're asking about a generalisation of this to include arbitrary signs. If you edit your question to be described concisely in terms of that, it might get more attention.
